# Sending custom props to custom component is failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have created a custom component which takes a color name from the parent component and updates that color in the state in the parent component. Currently, after I have done all the code, it does not save the new color, and therefore, does not update the the state.

This is for a react-native android app that I am building. I have looked at the ReactNative documentation for flatlist and textinput. I have looked at Stack overflow for solutions too

Set up a react native project. this is my parent component

```
class HomePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = { 
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      availableColors: [
             {name: 'red'}
           ]
     }

     this.changeColor = this.changeColor.bind(this)
     this.newColor = this.newColor.bind(this)

  }

  changeColor(backgroundColor){
    this.setState({
       backgroundColor,
    })

  }

  newColor(color){
const availableColors = [
  ...this.state.availableColors,
  color
]
this.setState({
  availableColors
})

  }

  renderHeader = ()=>{
    return(
    <ColorForm  onNewColor={this.newColor} />
    )

  }

  render() { 

    const { container, row, sample, text, button } = style
    const { backgroundColor, availableColors } = this.state

    return (
<View style={[container,{backgroundColor}, {flex: 1}]}   >
           <FlatList  

        data={availableColors}
        renderItem={
                    ({item}) => 
                            <ColorButton 
                                backgroundColor={item.name} 
                                onSelect={(color)=>{this.changeColor(color)}}> 
                                {item.name} 
                            </ColorButton>}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
        >
    </FlatList>
</View>

     );
  }
}
```

this is the code for ColorForm component

```
class ColorForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            txtColor:'',
         }

         this.submit = this.submit.bind(this)
    }

    submit() {
        this.props.onNewColor(this.state.txtColor.toLowerCase())
        this.setState({
            txtColor: 'yellow',

        })
    }
    render() { 
        const {container, txtInput, button} = style
        return ( 
        <View style={container}>

            <TextInput style={txtInput}
             placeholder="Enter a color"
             onChangeText={(txtColor)=>this.setState({txtColor})}
             value={this.state.txtColor}></TextInput>

            <Text 
            style={button}
            onPress={this.submit}>Add</Text>

        </View> );
    }


}
```

and below is the code for ColorButton component

```
export default ({backgroundColor, onSelect=f=>f}) => {
    const {button, row, sample, text} = style
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>{onSelect(backgroundColor)}} underlayColor="orange" style={button}>
        <View style={row}>
        <View style={[sample,{backgroundColor}]}></View>
        <Text style={text}>{backgroundColor}</Text>
      </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
}
```

The imports and stylesheets are setup as standard and do not effect the code so I have chosen to not show them.

EDIT: Adding the expo snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/@sarthakbatra/healthy-cake).

Expected Behavior:

When I press "ADD" on the ColorForm component, it should take that color and add that to the this.state.availableColor array and therefore visible in the ColorButton component. And when I touch the button, it should make that change

Current behaviour:

When I enter a color and press on add, it makes an empty button in the ColorButton component - NOT the color i entered in the color I entered in the ColorForm component.

EDIT: Adding the expo snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/@sarthakbatra/healthy-cake).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state is updating but the FlatList is not updating. Because your data={availableColors} in flatlist is not changing but your state is changing . 
Try to add [extraData](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#extradata)

**A marker property for telling the list to re-render (since it implements PureComponent). If any of your renderItem, Header, Footer, etc. functions depend on anything outside of the data prop, stick it here and treat it immutably.**

**Try this**

```
<FlatList  
  extraData={this.state.backgroundColor}
```

**Updated Answer**
the problem is in this function **newColor(color)**

```
const availableColors = [
  ...this.state.availableColors,
  color
]
```

you just receive a string of color but you have defined object like this {name: 'red'}

**please use this code**

```
 newColor(color){
const availableColors = [
  ...this.state.availableColors,
  {name: color}
]
this.setState({
  availableColors
})

  }
```

Snack link with example : https://snack.expo.io/@mehran.khan/healthy-cake-state-sample

**Also add export default to main component to remove error of launch**

```
export default class HomePage extends Component {
```

**App Preview**
[image]

Comment: Hey @Mehran , I looked at extraData prop and while it does make sense, the result is still the same as above, ie, the actual behavior is still the same. Is there any cloud service where I can host the code snippet so that I can add a working prototype in the answer. That way, people will have betterunderstanding as to what I am saying.

Comment: I made the snack. How do I embed it here. Sorry, if I sound like a noob. I am new to react-native. @IPutuYogaPermana

Comment: @Sarthak Batra Answer update with snack link . please check it and upvote and correct  my answer if helpful

Comment: @MehranKhan Yes, your answer helped. Thank you. Though, I do find it relevant to mark my question with the answer inside it (I will give you the credit there too.).. This is so that the next person who comes looking for a solution doesnt get confused because I made a mistake in the code. Sounds good?

Answer (score 0):

I had many problems using setState() in the way you are using now. I recommend you to use in this way setState(), with a callback:

```
this.setState((previousState, currentProps) => {
    return { ...previousState, foo: currentProps.bar };
});
```

This is one of [the article](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3) that talks about it.

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later.

From react website [setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).